# How can I save association information before the association is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, callback

Say a `User` has many `Photos`. I want to name each `photo` like so:

```
def safe_name
  self.name = "#{user.code}#{user.photos.count + 1}"
end
```

And validate this name when the association is saved. I can call that method in an `after_save` and have it work but the name of the photo shouldn't be blank beforehand. How can I grab it before the photo is saved so it's valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `before_validation` callback

Comment: Problem is I can't access `user` as a relation in the name before the `photo` is saved.

Comment: You can, you just do it like this:

@photo = user.photos.create(your attributes here)

this way you will have user_id in Photo instance. You run the callback in the photo model before validation, then your validation to check if the name is correct

Comment: That's not bad but I'd rather leave the logic out of the controller. Seems like it can't be done model-side though? I've got it passing all my tests with a temporary name so far that renames itself once the `photo` is saved.

Comment: There is no extra logic in the controller here. Its all standard. Extra logic goes in before_validate callback that you put in the Photo model.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate data and then validate it you can use the Active Record callback before_validation. This will modify the name and then call your validators.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Problem is I can't access `user` as a relation in the name before the `photo` is saved.